# $\lvert G\rvert=24$ not simple by a counting arguments

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I want to prove that $\lvert G\rvert=24$, then it has a non-trivial normal subgroup.

Here is my attempt:

$n_2$: number of 2-Sylow subgroup; $n_3$: number of 3-Sylow subgroup.

$n_2\in\{1,3\},\:\:n_3\in\{1,4\}$ by Sylow's Theorem.

Suposse $n_2=3$, $n_3=4$.

$n_3=4$ means there are 4 Sylow subgroups of order 3, which means 8 elements of order 3.

$n_2=3$ means there are 3 Sylow subgroups of order 8. Suppose $P_1,P_2,P_3$.
Using $\lvert P_1P_2\rvert\leq 24$, then $2<\lvert P_1\cap P_2\rvert <8$, so it is 4.

Suppose $P_1=\{1,a_1,\ldots,a_7\}$.

$\lvert P_1\cap P_2\rvert=4 \Longrightarrow P_2=\{1,a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ for example.

$\lvert P_1\cap P_3\rvert=4$ and $\lvert P_3\cap P_2\rvert=4$ $\Longrightarrow P_3=\{1,a_7,a_6,a_5,b_1,b_2,b_3,c\}$ for example.

Then we have 12 different elements of even order.

Adding we get 21 different elements.

Comment: I am trying to prove it using counting arguments

Comment: The main argument is that we can embedd such a simple group $G$ into $S_3$, see above, and then a trivial counting gives a contradiction, because $S_3$ has only $6$ elements.

Comment: A counting argument has to somehow take into account the fact that there exists a non-simple group of order $24$, $n_2=3$, $n_3=4$. Namely $S_4$. I'm not sure how to best use a counting argument to prove that there has to be a normal subgroup. Anyway, $S_4$ has the property that $P_1,P_2,P_3$ all intersect in a subgroup of size four, and that subgroup is then normal. If you can prove that necessarily $P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3$ has to be non-trivial that would do it.

Comment: I would consider "counting" the number of Sylow 2-subgroups a counting argument, per the other Question on this topic.  If there is a more limited notion of "counting argument" to be applied, it should be appropriately framed in this Question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why $\lvert P_1\cap P_2\rvert=4$ implies $P_1\cap P_2$ is normal?

Comment: I meant that $P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3$ has four elements (and is normal). Sorry about not making it clear that I meant that all three Sylow 2-subgroups share a subgroup of size four (in the case of $S_4$).

Comment: Ok. Here's a thought. Can you show that $(P_1\cap P_2)\cap P_3$ is non-trivial. That will do it, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't understand why $P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3$ has four elements

Comment: It has when $G=S_4$. That's all I said. So a counting argument that does not use simplicity cannot disprove it. I used $S_4$ only as an example in thinking how the Sylow 2-subgroups may intersect. I'm leading up to a solution :-)

Comment: Do you also see, how to conclude the claim, if it should happen that $|P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3|=2$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't see why $P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3$ has to be non-trivial

Comment: @user203327: Use inclusion/exclusion: $$|P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3| = |P_1| + |P_2| + |P_3| - |P_1\cap P_2| - |P_2\cap P_3| - |P_1\cap P_3| + |P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3|$$

Comment: @hardmath: No one else seems to bite. Would you expand your argument to an answer, please? I think excl/incl is the closest thing to a counting argument that we have here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'll add such as CW to the old Question, since it is another means to an end.